# Twilio "Connect Call To" Widget - How does it operate when a phone is switched off?

Tags: twilio, voip, twilio-api, twilio-studio

I have a Studio Flow set up in Twilio's API. It works in the following way:

1. If the first person doesn't pick up after 5 seconds it diverts to another phone.
2. If the second person doesn't pick up it diverts to our pre-recorded voicemail not attributed to either phone, but uploaded to twilio assets
3. the callers voice note is emailed to our inbox if they choose to leave a voicemail.

The first person is on annual leave and the corresponding phone is likely out of battery. I noticed the past two days that our office hasn't received any phone calls at all. When I check our logs, calls have been coming in and there are no errored logs, but they do not reach me as the second person.

Will the flow still execute if the first persons device isn't switched on?

I created a new flow to route to the second persons phone directly, if it wasn't answered, the voicenote would play in the same fashion. I tested this and it works perfectly.